# Warning - whose view is not in the window hierarchy in IOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created two view controllers, `ViewControllerOne`  and `DetailViewController` . And I gave an action to a  `UIButton`, when the button is pressed it will go to second view controller,

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
self.loginButton.hidden= YES;
self.aview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"authentication.png"]];

LAContext* context = [[LAContext alloc]init];
NSError* error = nil;

if ([context canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&error]) {
    [context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics localizedReason:@"Authenticate with Touch ID" reply:^(BOOL success, NSError*error){
        if (success) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.loginButton.hidden= NO;
                self.aview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                DetailViewController* detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
              [self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];


            });  }
```

but its giving the error,

```
<ViewController: 0x7f97e9da7d60> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

When button pressed its moves to `DetailViewController` but the screen is black, its not showing the details in `DetailViewController`.

Comment: You may want to check the [documentation on segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/chapters/StoryboardSegue.html).

Comment: I want to give the segue programmatically. Actually i am giving this method  when user's touch id match go to DetailViewController. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have added your DetailViewController in storyboard, you may have to **refer the same from storyboard while instantiating**.

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"your_storyboard_name" bundle: nil];
DetailViewController *detailViewController = (DetailViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"your_storyboard_identifier"];
[self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When you are initiating using alloc/init, it's simply instantiating a blank view controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Rashmi  .......Now the problem solved its running, but still its showing the error...whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: I'm not sure which view is not in the window!! Is it ViewControllerOne or DetailViewController? Depends on how are you adding the ViewControllerOne on the main window.

Comment: Found it. That error is for UIAlertController. Thanks